# Using an intent to send email outside of an activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity "Results" which does some calculations, and a button for the user to send an email containing those results. I have made a class called "Sender" to accomplish this, but startActivity isn't working in my Sender class. I know the actual intent works, because I could get it to work inside of my Results activity, just not in the Sender class.

```
public class Results extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          Button sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resultsEMAIL);
          sendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Sender sender = new Sender();
            sender.sendEmail();
        }
    });
```

///////

```
public class Sender{

public void sendEmail(){ 
  Intent sendEmail = new
  Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE); 

  ArrayList<Uri>uris = new ArrayList<Uri>(); 
  uri.add(someUri);
  uri.add(otherUri);

sendEmail.setType("message/rfc822");
  sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, allEmails);
  sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject"); 
  sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, results);
sendEmail.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uris);

    try {
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmail, "Send")); } 
    catch
    (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
    { Toast.makeText(context, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
  }
```

I have tried passing the context from Results

```
Results.context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(SendEmail,"Send"));
```

And I have also tried

```
sendEmail.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Regardless of what I do, I get the exception

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Should I just abandon trying to do this in a separate class?? I wanted to make a Sender class to clean up Results.

Comment: Little of this code will compile. For example, `Sender` does not have a `startActivity()` method, there is no `StartActivity()` method (with a capital `S`) in the Android SDK, etc. I suggest that you post the actual code that you successfully compiled and ran, and post the complete Java stack trace associated with any crashes from that code.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Sender does have a startActivity(). It's in try{}. But you're right about the capital S. That was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass **Context** of the activity to sendMail() method.

```
 public class Results extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Button sendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resultsEMAIL);
      sendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

        Sender sender = new Sender();
        sender.sendEmail(Results.this);
    }
});
```

And in your sendMail() method use context to start activity.

```
    public void sendEmail(Context context){ 
        Intent sendEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE); 

         //set data to intent
         context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmail, "Send")); 
     }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Much appreciated!